# Background job using ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is it a good idea to use Web API to run background jobs where each job can take between 1-4 hours to complete?

Problem: sometimes I noticed that the job restarts when a worker process is recycled.

Are there any other, better options to run background jobs on a Windows server?

Comment: you can use Windows Service to run any long-running background process. You can follow the links for more details. [Windows service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) , [Background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Agree with csharpd : your background task might even run twice on recycle. Because next worker process might start while the old one is still running

Comment: Web applications are good at one thing: servicing HTTP requests. Request comes in, Response goes out. Requests generally shouldn't take more than a few seconds from start to finish. Web applications are not good at handling long running tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options that are out there which can use to implement and run scheduled jobs in ASP.NET. Some of the popular out there are Quartz.Net - https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/, FluentScheduler - https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler and HangFire - https://www.hangfire.io/ .

Here are some great examples that might help you get started:
(1)Scheduled Tasks In ASP.NET With Quartz.Net[^] - https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net
(2)Schedule Background Jobs Using Hangfire In ASP.NET Core[^] -
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/schedule-background-jobs-using-hangfire-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I am already using Hangfire to schedules the jobs but what if the work process gets recycle while running the job. I think as @csharpd said is correct to use windows service for long-running background jobs.